# What is the easiest way to drop shot on MW3?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

So I've seen people do these "drop shots" and I've started to learn to do them but not amazing at them yet. I can still go 50 kills to 5-6 deaths without, but would prevent so many deaths if I could drop shot. What's the easiest way to do this? And how do you do a good "drop shot" to win in 1 v 1 situations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To perform a "Drop Shot" (going prone immediately after you encounter another player) you just have to hold the crouch/prone button as you start to fire.  The tricky part is doing this while keeping control of the other aspects of the game.

On the console, most "drop shotters" swear by the tactical controller layout, which puts the "crouch" button on your right stick button, but you'll have to be careful not to move your thumb as you click it, otherwise your aim will be off.  You might want to take a look at [alternative controllers](http://www.razerzone.com/minisite/onza), some of which put buttons where you can reach them with other fingers.

With a PC, you can rebind your keys so that you can access the buttons for "Aim Down Sights," "Fire Weapon," "Movement," and "Prone" simultaneously.  If you're using WASD for movement, you're probably using three buttons on your left hand for that, so you've got your pinky and thumb on the left hand you could rebind.  On your right hand, you might try using a mouse that gives you one or more thumb buttons to use.

Note that also going prone means that you can't track left/right as easily as you can otherwise, and that you're at a mobility disadvantage - grenades and other explosive weapons become harder to dodge.

Comment: Make sure to answer for both PC and console if you can.

Comment: Edited to add PC recommendations as well.  Good call.

Answer (score 2):

i started to write something on my own, but then i found [this article on wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Dropshot-in-Call-of-Duty) that explains the whole thing very good - just take a look at it. basically: get down and start firing as fast as you can. the better your speed of reaction gets, the better the results will be.

Answer (score -1):

Drop shotting is great, I love to do it. My recommended class for dropshotting and jumpshotting is mp7 w/rds kick scavenger pro, quickdraw pro, stalker pro.

Strike package is reaper, ac130, jugg. I get ac130 maybe once every 4-5 games.

Comment: Hi there.  This isn't a forum website, and your post doesn't *really* answer the question.  Can you see about removing all of the extraneous information, and just leaving the parts that answer the question?